# How to know when an application start?

Tags: c#

- I am creating an application in C# for monitoring some applications, so how to know when an exe running (ex: notepad).
- I tried using `timer` run check `if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)` every 1s but maybe not the good way.

Comment: what exactly you want to know ? That the given application(say Notepad) is currently running or not ? or you want to know the time of its execution since you tried using Timer

Comment: i want know when notepad start, i tried using if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0) every 1s.

Comment: then you already did the right thing

Comment: this can be simply done by using a infinite while loop. see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach would be to set timer which will check for running processes every, let's say, 5 seconds. In timer `Tick` event, check  for running process by it's name

```
// This will return an empty array if notepad isn't running.
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

take a look at [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i'm building an application same for u. It's is my solution:

```
public void findProcess(string processName)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
            while(true)
            {
                Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach(var p in process )
                    if(p.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
                    {
                        // TODO:
                    }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }            
        };
    }
```